# iOS 9 crash in WebCore::FrameView::contentsSizeRespectingOverflow:

Tags: uiwebview, ios-simulator, ios9

We just upgraded to Xcode 7 and when we run our e-reader app in a simulator with 9.0 it crashes in WebCore

WebCore::FrameView::contentsSizeRespectingOverflow:

We have to turn through a few pages (10 or 20) to reproduce it. The strange thing is I can't reproduce it on a device or when running on simulator with 8.4.

I know it helps to set the scalesPageToFit property of UIWebView to NO, but we are already doing that.

Has anyone else seen this issue and was able to come up with a work-around?

Thank you

Comment: Please file a radar at http://bugreport.apple.com including the crash report and a sample project.

Comment: Same problem here, Crashlytics is reporting a HUGE number of crashes affecting half of our user base. I'll file a radar as well, hopefully I can reproduce it so I can attach the log.

Comment: It would be good if anyone else who has this issue can try to confirm if it is fixed on beta 4 (now 5)

Answer (score 2):

Same here. That is my radar. Please also file one.

It might have been fixed in 9.1 beta 4 but I am getting a memory related crash in my test app on that version.

Comment: I was getting memory errors but I do only really see them on one device. Another that I have on beta 4 also does not seem to exhibit this crash any more.

Answer (score 1):

I have this issue too (I see in crashlitycs) but I can't reproduce it - I'm still work on it. Do You have any progress ?

I find this issue, maybe Yours:

https://openradar.appspot.com/22889402

**------------------------------------------------------------------**

Probably I find working workaround. 
I create new viewcontroller object only once, and switch off scale for pages that have own mobile version. Issue happen when uiwebview want scale page and page is originally fit for screen - when website is "big" issue not happen. But that I say - probably.

In crashlitycs I dont have this issue for 4 days, but this is not long time, so we will see.